# Pandas - Sort multi level data by column but preserve level group order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-level Dataframe with a column called `name`. I'd like to maintain the parent-child level grouping of data, but sort each level A-Z by this `name` column.

In other words, for each line, if the parent item is sorted, all the children items at lower level would also be sorted as a block.

**Here is an example of my current Dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['level', 'name'],                        
                  data=[['1','AAA'],                                  
                        ['1.1', 'ZZZ'],                               
                        ['1.2', 'XXX'],                               
                        ['1.3', 'YYY'],                               
                        ['1.3.1', 'GGG'],                             
                        ['1.3.1.1', 'XXX'],                           
                        ['1.3.2', 'EEE'],                             
                        ['1.3.3', 'FFF'],                             
                        ['1.3.3.1', 'TTT'],                           
                        ['1.3.3.2', 'SSS'],                           
                        ['2', 'CCC'],                                 
                        ['3', 'BBB'],                                 
                        ['3.1', 'AAA']])
```

**And how the sorted Dataframe should look:**

```
sorted_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['level', 'name'],                 
                  data=[['1','AAA'],           # No Change            
                        ['1.1', 'XXX'],        # Was 1.2              
                        ['1.2', 'YYY'],        # Was 1.3              
                        ['1.2.1', 'EEE'],      # Was 1.3.2            
                        ['1.2.2', 'FFF'],      # Was 1.3.3            
                        ['1.2.3', 'GGG'],      # Was 1.3.1            
                        ['1.2.3.1', 'XXX'],    # Was 1.3.1.1          
                        ['1.2.3.1', 'SSS'],    # Was 1.3.3.2          
                        ['1.2.3.2', 'TTT'],    # was 1.3.3.1          
                        ['1.3', 'ZZZ'],        # Was 1.1              
                        ['2', 'BBB'],          # Was 3                
                        ['2.1', 'AAA'],        # Was 3.1              
                        ['3', 'CCC']])         # Was 2
```

Breaking this down into steps:

1. Sort deepest level (i.e. X.X.X.X) by name. In the original DF above, 1.3.3.1 (SSS) and 1.3.3.2 (TTT) would swap. 1.3.1.1 (XXX) stays the same since there are no other items in the 1.3.1.X group.
2. Look at next level up (i.e. X.X.X - GGG, EEE, FFF). 1.3.1 (GGG) and all it's childen below (i.e. 1.3.1.1), need to move below the EEE and FFF (and their children). EEE and FFF (and their childen) are already in correct position.
3. Repeat this process at the next levels up, sorting the parents and all their children.

I tried breaking up the Dataframe into multiple indexes by spliting the level column by the dots:

```
df = pd.concat([df['level'].str.split('.', expand=True), df], axis=1) \
      .set_index([0,1,2,3])
```

Once I get to this point, I'm sorta stuck. I've tried various things (`sort_value`, `sort_index`, `reset_index`, etc.) but haven't been able to sort it out (pun intended). To further complicate things, the `'level'` could be an arbitrary length with my real data (ex. 1.2.2.1.2.3.1...) and the name column is also arbitrary (see how AAA repeats at different level in the example data).

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I've spent a couple hours researching and am banging my head trying to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fillna`:

```
df.join(df.level.str.split('.', expand=True).fillna(-1))\
  .sort_values([0,1,2,3])[['level','name']]
```

Output:

```
      level name
0         1  AAA
1       1.1  ZZZ
2       1.2  XXX
3       1.3  YYY
4     1.3.1  GGG
5   1.3.1.1  XXX
6     1.3.2  EEE
7     1.3.3  FFF
8   1.3.3.1  TTT
9   1.3.3.2  SSS
10        2  CCC
11        3  BBB
12      3.1  AAA
```

Unknown depth:

```
df.join(df.level.str.split('.', expand=True)).fillna(-1)\
  .pipe(lambda x: x.sort_values(x.filter(regex='\d+').columns.tolist()))[['level','name']]
```

Comment: @mattlapointe Not sure, if I missed something about the names column. In your question, the names changes levels from the input dataframe to the sorted dataframe.  Did I miss some sort of logic here?

Comment: Thanks Scott for the response, but not quite what I'm looking to do. I need to sort by the `name` column - I don't think this was totally clear in the original question. I added some clarification above.